# How can I mount a tablet on a wall?

Tags: mounting

Expanding my music set-up, I'm planning to mount a tablet in my kitchen mostly as remote-control (for music playing on the server), but as it can also show websites and movies, it might get -sporadically- used as a 'real' screen too.

I've done all the things I'm comfortable with (server, networking, audio, etc), but now it's on hold because the current card-board "stand" on the kitchen top just won't do and I'm at a loss on how to mount this on the wall.

---

**The possible locations are limited:**

- On a tiled-wall right next to the stove (at eye-height)
- Behind the stove on a wall, between some racks: there's not enough space for it to be mounted there 'against' the wall, so some sort of arm has to be used I think

*The tablet's specs are:*

- No mount points/VESA/Screw-points available
- Weighs about 550 grams
- Size hxb 21+cm x 16+cm  (a couple of mm wider on each side), about 1.5cm thick

---

Some specs I'm thinking of (do DIY-ers also talk "[MoSCoW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MoSCoW_Method)"? :)  )

**Must-have:**

- Holds the tablet safely

**Should-have**

- Wires can run from tablet (at least power, maybe audio later)
- Landscape orientation

**Could-have**

- Rotation to Portrait
- Turning (viewing angle)
- Movement (from/towards you, maybe left/right/up/down etc)

I wasn't really sure if this was too hobby-like to be ontopic, but [meta seems not to mind](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/569/line-where-hobby-starts-is-this-ontopic), so here we are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hook and loop tape. adhesive to the tablet. You might get away with adhesive to the wall too, but you might prefer to screw a thin plastic panel to the wall and stick the fuzzy (loop) side of the tape to that for better adhesion.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  We generally call it "velcro" over here.

Comment: I generally call it velcro too. "other hook and loop products are available"

Comment: I'll see where I can get some "klitteband"-tape (to further confuse the language thing ;P ) around here maybe, good point.

Comment: You can also put a piece of ***(insert name here) and mount your tablet to someplace in your car and use the GPS feature. (No watching movies or checking emails)

Comment: As a followup: Fixed. Done. Happy :). Now I'm looking for a) places where I can put the tablet (as @lqlarry said: car, more?) and b) looking for stuff I want to attach to my kitchen wall. Maybe I shouldn't have bought this much of the stuff, it is great fun :). Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

You could get some aluminum C-channel (available at most hardware stores) and mount it on the wall at the top and bottom and slide the tablet in from the side.

It provides none of the movement features you might like but it is dead simple and if the c-channel is mounted well you should not have to worry about it falling.

This might be a problem if you need access to the side of the tablet that is in the channel but holes could be drilled in the c-channel.

Comment: Sounds good, more sturdy then the velcro option, but also a bit less versatile. Have to think about it. How would you mount the C-channel on the wall? A simple screw doesn't seem to simple for my beginner-brain, as you don't have the space for a screwdriver or such, because of it being all `[` shaped I suppose?

Comment: Pre-drill though one side of the `[` so you can get the screwdriver head through the c channel to the other side and screw is in?

Answer (score 1):

There are brackets for this type of thing:

http://store.apple.com/us/product/H2345ZM/A

The technique I like is mounting in a cabinet door:

http://mashable.com/2010/05/04/ipad-kitchen-cabinet/

In either case, I wouldn't mount it behind the stove. Bacon grease and touch screens don't mix.

Comment: But bacon grease goes with everything!

Comment: It's _not_ an ipad, so I doubt those will fit ;). I'm not really afraid for the grease, there's some extra space around.

Comment: @Nanne those examples could be used for most any tablet (at least the cabinet version). The issue with putting it near the stove is partially grease, but also other factors: lots of steam (really bad for electronics), the fact that you may have to reach across the stove to use it, etc. Just be careful when considering a mount near the stove.

Comment: thanks for the warning! I don't see anything about being compatiblility though